# parsing json in java with "-" character before attribute name

Tags: java, json, character

i am trying to parse following json file.

```
"ItemData" : [{
        "-item" : "A",
        "id" : "100",
        "name" : "abc",
        "description" : "abcd",
        "category" : "xyz",
    }
]
```

I am able to parse everything except first field. Its because of "-" character in the beginning. I tried using @SerializedName("-item") in my POJO file. But does not work.

Can anybody tell me how can i parse this field?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse"? Did you write a parser on your own or do you use some existing library/API?

Comment: Are u stucked with the json format? u can remove "-".

Comment: Which parser are you using?

Comment: i am using gson library.And i cant remove "-".

Comment: First thing, this is not pure json. You should read json formatting and parsing.

Comment: it is a pure json...and i am even able to parse it using gson without "-".You may be thinking its not pure json becuase i have not uploaded full json and just 1 block of it.

Comment: Looks like the JsonFieldNameValidator does not like the leadingh '-'. Not sure what they mean by "valid JSON field names", if I read json.org correctly any string is a valid key. As a workaround, you could preprocess the file and replace this field name globally. This should be relatively safe because the string '"-item":' cannot occur in a value because the quotes would need to be escaped there. It also cannot be a value itself if you include the colon in the string to replace.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how your code looks like but `@SerializedName("-item")` seems to be working fine for me

```
class Data {
    private List<ItemData> ItemData = new ArrayList<ItemData>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [ItemData=" + ItemData + "]";
    }
}

class ItemData {

    @SerializedName("-item")
    private String _item;

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String category;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ItemData [_item=" + _item + ", id=" + id + ", name=" + name
                + ", description=" + description + ", category=" + category
                + "]";
    }
}
```

Usage

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

String jsonString = "{\r\n" + " \"ItemData\" : [{\r\n"
        + "         \"-item\" : \"A\",\r\n" + "         \"id\" : \"100\",\r\n"
        + "         \"name\" : \"abc\",\r\n"
        + "         \"description\" : \"abcd\",\r\n"
        + "         \"category\" : \"xyz\"\r\n" + "     }\r\n" + "  ]\r\n"
        + "}\r\n";

Data item = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
System.out.println(item);
```

Output

```
Data [ItemData=[ItemData [_item=A, id=100, name=abc, description=abcd, category=xyz]]]
                          ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: That helped...actually my problem was the POJO which i was using was extending another POJO class..and it turns out that i have to give @SerializedName("-item") in parent POJO too.